# Match function to look for a value, if blank look for a different value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form, that when you use the "Update" or "Delete" buttons it uses the match function to update a row in the table.

I'm trying to look for the "Employee ID" first and if not there look for "Position ID" to identify the row to edit.

Is there a way to do this or should I be using a different function?

This is the VBA code I have for the "Update" button. This matches one value. The "Delete" button is similar.

```vb
Private Sub BTN02_Update_Click()

If Me.TB01_EmployeeID = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select the record to update."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Data")
    Dim Selected_Row As Long
    Selected_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value, sh.Range("A:A"), 0)
    
    sh.Range("A" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TB01_EmployeeID
    sh.Range("B" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TB02_FirstName
    sh.Range("C" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TB03_LastName
    sh.Range("D" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB01_Postition
    sh.Range("E" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TB04_PostitionID
    sh.Range("F" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TB05_HireDate
    sh.Range("G" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB02_PayType
    sh.Range("H" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB03_Status
    sh.Range("I" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB04_Shift
    sh.Range("J" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB05_Supervisor
    sh.Range("K" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB06_Department
    sh.Range("L" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB07_DepartmentCode
    sh.Range("M" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.TB06_Birthday
    sh.Range("N" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB08_ShirtSize
    sh.Range("O" & Selected_Row).Value = Me.CB09_Veteran
    
    Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value = ""
    Me.TB02_FirstName.Value = ""
    Me.TB03_LastName.Value = ""
    Me.CB01_Postition.Value = ""
    Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value = ""
    Me.TB05_HireDate.Value = ""
    Me.CB02_PayType.Value = ""
    Me.CB03_Status.Value = ""
    Me.CB04_Shift.Value = ""
    Me.CB05_Supervisor.Value = ""
    Me.CB06_Department.Value = ""
    Me.CB07_DepartmentCode.Value = ""
    Me.TB06_Birthday.Value = ""
    Me.CB08_ShirtSize.Value = ""
    Me.CB09_Veteran.Value = ""
    
    MsgBox "Record Updated"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: test IF "employee ID" is blank or not in the range of existing values then do the other.

Comment: I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Just asks me to "Select a record to update."

Comment: is this what you were thinking? 

    Selected_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.if(Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value = "", (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.TB04_PostitionID, sh.Range("E:E"), 0)), (Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value, sh.Range("A:A"), 0)))

Comment: maybe try to use find method ... something like this : `set c =  sh.columns(1).find(TB01_EmployeeID.Value, lookat:=xlwhole` ---> this is to check if the value in tb01EmpID exist in column A, `if not c is nothing then seleted_row = c.row` if found then the selected row is the row of the found cell (the c). `else` .... `set c = sh.columns(4).find(TB04_PostitionID.value,lookat:=xlwhole` ---> so, if the EmpId is not found in column A, then this is to check if tb04PosID is found in column 4. `if not c is nothing then selected_row = c.row:else exit sub` ... `end if`.

Comment: Would I need to add a "Dim" to be able to set "C"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set empidrng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lrowempid)` is column A (A2 to last row with value) where the employee ID  are located and where the employee ID will be searched from the value of the `Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value`

`Set posidrng = sh.Range("E2:E" & lrowposid)` is column E (E2 to last row with value) where the position ID  are located and where the position ID will be searched from the value of the `Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value`

`Set foundID = empidrng.Find(Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` this will find the employee ID in range `empidrng` with the employee ID value from `Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value`

if not found

it will search for the position ID which is `Set foundID = posidrng.Find(Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` this will find the position ID in range `posidrng` with the position ID value from the `Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value`

if not found again it will display a message that the employee id and postion id are not found and will exit the sub

if `Set foundID = empidrng.Find(Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` is found it will get the row number of the found cell then update from column A to O all in the same row according to the corresponding textboxes and comboboxes value, it will not trigger the `Set foundID = posidrng.Find(Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` anymore

then same process for `Set foundID = posidrng.Find(Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` but only if triggered

```
Private Sub BTN02_Update_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lrowempid As Long, lrowposid As Long
Dim foundID As Range, empidrng As Range, posidrng As Range

If Me.TB01_EmployeeID = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select the record to update."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Data")
lrowempid = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row'last row column A
lrowposid = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row'last row column E
Set empidrng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lrowempid)  'edit A2 to A1 if no header
Set posidrng = sh.Range("E2:E" & lrowposid)  'edit E2 to E1 if no header

Set foundID = empidrng.Find(Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If foundID Is Nothing Then
'edit correct name of position id text box
    Set foundID = posidrng.Find(Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
End If
If foundID Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Employee or Position ID not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
    
sh.Range("A" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.TB01_EmployeeID
sh.Range("B" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.TB02_FirstName
sh.Range("C" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.TB03_LastName
sh.Range("D" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB01_Postition
sh.Range("E" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.TB04_PostitionID
sh.Range("F" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.TB05_HireDate
sh.Range("G" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB02_PayType
sh.Range("H" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB03_Status
sh.Range("I" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB04_Shift
sh.Range("J" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB05_Supervisor
sh.Range("K" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB06_Department
sh.Range("L" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB07_DepartmentCode
sh.Range("M" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.TB06_Birthday
sh.Range("N" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB08_ShirtSize
sh.Range("O" & foundID.Row).Value = Me.CB09_Veteran

Me.TB01_EmployeeID.Value = ""
Me.TB02_FirstName.Value = ""
Me.TB03_LastName.Value = ""
Me.CB01_Postition.Value = ""
Me.TB04_PostitionID.Value = ""
Me.TB05_HireDate.Value = ""
Me.CB02_PayType.Value = ""
Me.CB03_Status.Value = ""
Me.CB04_Shift.Value = ""
Me.CB05_Supervisor.Value = ""
Me.CB06_Department.Value = ""
Me.CB07_DepartmentCode.Value = ""
Me.TB06_Birthday.Value = ""
Me.CB08_ShirtSize.Value = ""
Me.CB09_Veteran.Value = ""

MsgBox "Record Updated"

End Sub
```

Comment: I coded that in, and it doesn't give me an error but it also do not update the row.

Comment: @amellady2 check that the textbox name are correct in your explanation you say "position id" but in your code it is `TB04_PostitionID` , also put a `Debug.Print Selected_Row` after the End If line to see in the immediate window what is the value of the `Selected_Row`

Comment: I'm guessing it was a spelling mistake. I copied the name from the properties window for the "Position ID" and it works sort of. It will edit a row, but not the right one. it just saves over the first row.

Comment: @amellady2 see updated code above using the find function

Comment: When I clicked to update button, it edited row 2, but the record it needed to change was row 38. Again, sorry new to this and don't quite understand the coding you added. would i need to edit the "empidrng" or the "posidrng" to get it to look at the right row? it reads like it would just edit the 2nd row.

Comment: @amellady2 see explanation of the code above, make sure the employee id value is really in the `TB01_EmployeeID` text box and the position id value is in the `TB04_PostitionID` text box

Comment: I got it to work with your code! I somehow changed the name of something after I added in your code.  Sorry for that, but also thank you for explaining what the code was doing!!!